# How do I use MacPorts' Perl installation with MAMP?

Tags: macos, mysql, perl, macports

I have MAMP 3.0.6 and MacPorts 2.3.1. There are some Perl modules that I need to use (through some CGI scripts), I installed them on the MacPorts Perl installation (e.g., `p5.16-dbd-mysql`), but I can't figure out how to get MAMP to use the right Perl installation. One error is as follows:

```
install_driver(mysql) failed: Can't locate DBD/mysql.pm in @INC (@INC contains: ../../lib /Library/Perl/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.16 /Network/Library/Perl/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Network/Library/Perl/5.16 /Library/Perl/Updates/5.16.2 /System/Library/Perl/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/5.16 /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.16 .) at (eval 10) line 3.
Perhaps the DBD::mysql perl module hasn't been fully installed,
or perhaps the capitalisation of 'mysql' isn't right.
Available drivers: DBM, ExampleP, File, Gofer, Proxy, SQLite, Sponge.
```

I tried setting my `.bashrc` file but it doesn't seem to help

```
export PERL5LIB=/opt/local/lib/perl5
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that MAMP—and specifically the Apache install in MAMP—cannot see the module. So you need to adjust the Apache config in this file:

> /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf

To have something like this appended to it—make sure to adjust those paths to match your real/working environment—or adjusted if these lines already exist:

> SetEnv PATH /opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
>
> SetEnv PERL5LIB  /usr/local/lib:/opt/local/lib/perl5

Then restart the Apache webserver in MAMP and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks. This certainly helped. Now I got an error:
`Perl lib version (5.16.3) doesn't match executable 'the_path_to_cgi.cgi' version (v5.16.2) at /opt/local/lib/perl5/5.16.3/darwin-thread-multi-2level/Config.pm line 60.`
I have upgraded all my ports, rebooted the machine, but still see this. Any suggestions? btw, it looks like the second line needs to be:
`SetEnv PERL5LIB /usr/local/lib:/opt/local/lib/perl5/5.16.3`

Comment: UPDATE: turns out I have another installation of perl at `/usr/bin/perl`. I renamed it and it's working fine now. Thanks!